# How to monitor fargate ECS web app timeouts in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a simple setup: Fargate ECS cluster with ALB, running web API.

I want to monitor (and ring alarms) the number of requests timed out for my web app. The only metric close to that I found in CloudWatch is `AWS/ApplicationELB` -> `TargetResponseTime`
But, it seems like requests that timed out from the ALB point of view are not recorded there at all.

How do you monitor ALB timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only from **ALB time out requests point of view.**

It is confusing because there is not a specific metric which is termed or contains `timeout`.

ALB Timeout generates an [HTTP 408](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-408-issues) error code for which ALB internally increments the `HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count`.

From the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#elevated-processing-time)

> The load balancer sends the HTTP code to the client, saves the request to the access log, and increments the HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count or HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count metric.

In my view you can set up  a CloudWatch alarm to monitor `HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count`metric and initiate an action (such as sending a notification to an email address) if the metric goes outside what you consider an acceptable range.

More details about the `HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count` -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html

Comment: Thank you for the clue! I noticed my ALB producing `504 Gateway Time-out` so in my case the `HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count` metric (per ELB/AZ) seems to work as expected. Too bad we cannot filter them per target group though. Also, we should use `Sum` aggregation only, all others will give 1.

Comment: Glad it helped :), yes `cannot filter them per target group` because `This count does not include response codes generated by targets.`, it is in the metric description, even about the sum aggregation `The most useful statistic is Sum. Minimum, Maximum, and Average all return 1.` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html